# Can one calculate the electric conductivity of iron?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Iron is a commonplace material. It is common knowledge that it conducts.
Is it possible to accurately calculate the electric conductivity of iron? With what kind of method? Up to what precision?

Comment: Commonplace Iron may not be pure. [Impurities](http://fog.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~wkaufmyn/ENGN45/Course%20Handouts/15_ElectricalProps/07_ImpuritiesConductivityConductors.html) have a significant effect.